# check consecutive digits in tuple

Tags: python, python-2.7, tuples

I'd like to check if the numbers inside a tuple are consecutive digits in ascending or descending order without repeat any digit i.e 12345 or 98765. What is the pythonist way to do that?

Comment: Question is a bit unclear, would you mind clarifying a bit more?

Comment: @KDawG Of course friend. I have a list with 10^5 tuples where each tuple has five digits (from 0 to 9) I'd like to know how many tuples are in order with consecutive digits (ascending or descending) i.e 12345 45678 87654 01234

Comment: @KDawG nope - that's not the same Q :)

Comment: @JonClements kinda Confused :p

Comment: @KDawG it's looking for numerically contigious ranges of numbers, not confirming that a sequence of `n` numbers is contigious ascending/descending

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it as follows:

```
a = (7,8,9,10,11,12)   #or any other sequence of integers

print set(y-x for x,y in zip(a,a[1:])) in ({1}, {-1})
```

This prints `True` if the numbers are consecutive in either ascending or descending order.

This code works as follows:

First, it calculates the differences between adjacent numbers

Second, it creates a set of those differences which basically means that it gets the unique set of differences ignoring duplicates.

Thirdly, it checks whether that set is either `{1}` or `{-1}` which means that the only difference is either all differ by 1 or all differ by -1.

Hope that is clear.

Comment: How could explain me your solution? thanks in advance @sshashank124

Comment: This is a great solution!

Comment: @jd1215, If my answer was helpful, would you mind accepting it? Thanks

Comment: @sshashank124 Oh friend sorry! I'll do it. One last question: How do you learn to program in that way?

Comment: @jd1215, Before I joined SO, I couldn't. After hanging around on the python tag page and seeing question and their extremely high quality answers, I was able to pick up a few tricks. :) It is, in my opinion, the best way to learn